# Images are not scaling on Foundation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

I have been playing around with the ZURB Foundation Framework on this site:
http://www.maxi-muth.de/test/zurb/

I used this Foundation Template: http://foundation.zurb.com/page-templates4/grid.html

It seems like it has problems with scaling the images.
By using **Chrome everything is displayed fine**.
In **Firefox** the images at the Landing Page are overlapping each others (/they are displayed in their original size (which is not happening in the original Foundation template)

Same is happening with the Foundation *Thumbnails* used here: http://www.maxi-muth.de/test/zurb/shortcodes

**What do I need to do to get** (back?) **the automatic scaling?**

Answer (score 2):

I think it's no real solution (because still the original file size is used), but by adding a max-width of 100% to the images, they suit their parent.

Comment: Thanks for the clue. I've found setting `width: 100%` on the image's containing `div` makes things work as expected in Firefox.